# Order object / Sql order by string not working properly with object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to sort an array of objects directly in the SQL query or with a Js function but the result is no sorted, or half of them are.

**This is my SQL call:**

```
controller.getCandidatos = (req, res) => {
  req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query('SELECT c.id, c.nombre, c.apellido, c.empresa, c.imagen, c.id_entidad, e.nombre as enti FROM candidato c left join entidad e on c.id_entidad = e.id ORDER BY c.nombre ASC', (err, rows) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      res.send(rows);
    });
  });
```

**And I get this:**

```
[
  { "id": 113, "nombre":" Antinori", "apellido": null, "empresa": "Cecilia Guzmán Arriagada", "imagen": null, "id_entidad": null, "enti": null },
  { "id": 67, "nombre": " Aresti", "apellido": null, "empresa": "Matías Rivera", "imagen": null, "id_entidad": null, "enti": null },
  { "id": 84, "nombre": " Balduzzi", "apellido": null, "empresa": "Gustavo  Balduzzi ", "imagen": null, "id_entidad": null, "enti": null },
....
{ "id": 108, "nombre": " Viu Manent", "apellido": null, "empresa": "José Miguel Viu", "imagen": null, "id_entidad": null, "enti": null },
  { "id": 13, "nombre": "Abraham Lincoln", "apellido": null, "empresa": "Estados Unidos", "imagen": "lincol.jpg", "id_entidad": null, "enti": null },
```

After that last object it start to sort well again from 'A' but the array its in half.

I was trying with this function but I got the same result.

```
function dynamicSort(property) {
        var sortOrder = 1;
        if(property[0] === "-") {
            sortOrder = -1;
            property = property.substr(1);
        }
        return function (a,b) {
            var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
            return result * sortOrder;
        }
    }
```

And the array sorting start getting weird when I order by other columns like 'apellido' in either way and IDK why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in the `nombre` column of the first few results you get start with a space.

Space comes before `a`, so the sorting is correct.

You can sort by the trimmed text:

```
... ORDER BY TRIM(c.nombre) ASC
```

(but this will prevent use of an index on `c.nombre`, if there is such; at least in the case of MySQL).

Comment: OMG and that take me so long to see u.u